# How to do multi file uploading in JQuery without form and giving remarks/comment for each file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multifile-uploader

I'm looking for some JQuery plugin/Plain JS to have multi file uploading without any forms. Also, have to provide remarks for each file(similar to Facebook albums). Need to save both file(as BLOB) and remarks in database using Java(Servlets). There should not be any file storage in server while doing this activities.

**Note:** I already had a look on jquery file upload, uploadify, etc. Not able to use those plugins according to requirement.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Nilambar After lot of googling still not able to get any fair amount of idea to start of with our requirements. Looking for initial push to start with, had a look on various plugins demo and none of them matching my expectation. So, as of now I don't have anything to show for you. Meantime, closed match one is JQuery file upload, I will try to do something on it. If you have any other suggestions to start, please let me know.